# i want to fetch a data from my sql table in Laravel where 2 unique keys are same in 2 diffrent colums but not working

Tags: mysql, laravel

discount table

```
category_id    discount_amount
  65                300
  65                300
  65                300
  66                400
  66                400
  66                400
  67                200
  67                200
  67                200
```

product table

```
product_id      category_id
  1                65
  2                66
  3                67
```

I want to fetch `discount_amount` according to `category_id` once no repetition

Comment: Show us some code please.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id, p.category_id, sum(discount_amount)
FROM product p
INNER JOIN discount d ON p.category_id = d.category_id 
GROUP BY product_id;
```

Output:

```
product_id, category_id, total discount amount

 1           65            900

 2           66           1200

 3           67           600
```

Comment: actually theses discounts are on location-based so that why they are repeating i don't want to sum up them

Comment: Could you please provide excepted result set